# Directshow real time compression to output small size video

Tags: c++, directshow, directshow.net, vfw

So i've made an application to view and capture video stream from WDM capture sources, my problem is that the file size is too big (i.e 7 min video would be 1.5 GB). I'm already using an encoder in my graph "ffdshow encoder" but i still need a more compressed output video.

This is the graph that i'm using:

[image: Directshow Graph]

I've tried to use other encoders like x264, x265 but after some search i found out that the encoder itself won't show up as a filter and it needs to be wrapped as VFW so i downloaded and installed the VFW wrappers for the x264 and x265 encoders. And still they didn't show up in the graph so i searched some more and found out that they only show up in the 32bit versions of graph editors and won't work/show up for a 64bit version of any software although and that's when i got stuck.

But after some more searching i came across this github project:

https://github.com/RenderHeads/DirectShow-vfwFilter

Which is basically a 64bit wrapper for the 32bit vfw (as far as i understood), so i downloaded it and gave it a try and after a few experiments i managed to output a relatively smaller video file using the x264vfw encoder. But my problem with that this filter was that it doesn't save its configuration as shown below

[image: VFW Wrapper]

And this is where i'm stuck right now, i need a good compressor/encoder to get a small output file.

Comment: The only decent stock encoder/compressor is Windows Media Video. It's use is a bit tricky because you end up having WMV/ASF file and you use profile-based WM ASF Writer filter. To get H.264 MP4 file, which is most popular nowadays, you will want a third party filter, e.g. [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/x264vfw/), or similar or commercial.

Comment: @RomanR. I already installed [x264vfw](https://sourceforge.net/projects/x264vfw/) but i wasn't able to use is in a 64bit environment.

Comment: For 64-bit app you need `x264vfw64`

Comment: I used that as well but still i can't access/use it.